# SQL select distinct by 2 or more columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, distinct, sql-server-2014

I have a table with a lot of columns and what I need to do is to write `select` that would take only unique values. The main problem is that I need to check three columns at the same time and if all three columns have same values in their columns(not between them, but in their own column) then `distinct`. Idea should be something like `distinct(column1 and column2 and column3)`

Any ideas? Or you need more information, because I'm not sure if everybody gets what I have in mind.

This is example. Select should return two rows from this, one where last column would have `Yes and other row with`No`.

[image: this is example]

Comment: it would be great  if you provide an example..

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle? This is typically done using window functions

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Microsoft SQL management studio. I think its Oracle.

Comment: could you add a definition for your tables and some test data in your question? and the result you require maybe

Comment: @user26409021 edited and added example.

Comment: @Macb3th what do you want your result to look like? As I understand you just want to get 2 rows from your result: NOR--Forecast-Canal Digital--Yes and NOR--Forecast-Canal Digital--No

Comment: @JeremyC. Yes, you are right.

Comment: Can you provide the column names?

Comment: @Macb3th then you don't need any complicated queries, just use SELECT DISTINCT col1,col2,col3 FROM tablename

Comment: @Macb3th check the answer by Mureinik and check this sqlfiddle to see if it's what you need: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3cb5c/1

Comment: @JeremyC. Am, how to use it if i need to select more columns, but they should not be in distinct?

Comment: could you give an example of what you mean? You might get inconsistent results if you do that

Comment: @JeremyC. Well there are more columns that i need to select, but only 3 of them need to DISTINCT. something like that SELECT col12, col10, DISTINCT col1,col2,col FROM table. something like that. but it doesn't work.

Comment: well I don't know if you want to do that, because then you would get only col12 and col10 from 1 record, is that what you want? if you do you can just do DISTINCT col1, col2, col3, max(col12), max(col10) but I'm telling you this will get you inconsistent data, better would be to just do DISTINCT col1, col2, col3, col10, col12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is exactly what the `distinct` keyword is for:

```
SELECT distinct col1, col2, col3
FROM   mytable
```